How to locally re-stain a wooden countertop?
I have a large wooden countertop that was badly damaged. It seems that in order to remove a stain, it was sanded or even scratched (as it is uneven) quite deep. It results on a large section with no stain, appearing greyish in the middle of the more yellow wood. (Picture attached)
This is highly problematic to me and I would like to correct this as much as possible.
Is there anything I can do? Products to apply to get close to the original color.
Many thanks.


First you need to determine if it is real wood or just a fake covering.  Real wood should be able to sand down and restain.  Fake you will probably want to make a design statement and make that area into a pot holder/whatever.

@crip659 Thank you for your answer. It is real wood, massive. It seems to lack varnish/lacquer, there's just wood. Is sanding down the only thing to do?

The grey is stained into the wood. The only way to get this counter back to a uniform color is sanding, sanding and more sanding.
Start with 100 grit an orbital sander is prefered. Bely sanders can make waves in the wood if not done perfectly. A Random orbital sander can get all the surface except in the corners. For corners use a sanding wedge on an oscillating tool
Sand the surface until the grey is removed and all or most of the original stain.  Continue sanding with finer grades like 150, 240 and  320.
When finished sanding clean the surface with a vacuum or a tack cloth to get all of the sanding dust off.
Stain the surface with a penetrating stain, color of your choice. When the stain is dry seal the surface with an oil based polyurethane. Apply 3 or 4 coats.  Lightly hand sand the first 2 coats with a 400 grit paper, to get a nice smooth surface. Apply the final coat and allow to dry at least overnight, possibly longer depending on the conditions.
